# Get TypeSyntax from ITypeSymbol

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm experimenting a bit with the Roslyn-CTP.

Currently I'm trying to replace `var` with the concrete type.

```
var i=1;
```

should become:

```
int i=1;
```

Figuring out the inferred type is easy. But since this part happens in the semantic model I get a `ITypeSymbol`. The replacement happens in the syntax model, so I need a `TypeSyntax`. Since I don't want a bloated name (`global::System.Int32`), the conversion is context dependent (`using`, nested types etc.).

The Visual studio version that's part of Roslyn already has this functionality in its "Simplify type name" quickfix, but looking over the samples I couldn't find an easy way to do this conversion.

---

Based on Kevin Pilch-Bisson's answer I'm now using:

```
var location = document.GetSyntaxTree().GetLocation(node);
string name = variableType.ToMinimalDisplayString((Location)location, (SemanticModel)document.GetSemanticModel());
```

A location which `ToMinimalDisplayString` can be obtained from a `CommonSyntaxTree`.

An additional complication is that `ToMinimalDisplayString` requires the classes `Location` and `SemanticModel`, whereas `document.GetSemanticModel()` and `CommonSyntaxTree.GetLocation` only return an interface.
I worked around by simply casting to the classes, which seems to work for now.

Hmm it looks like the classes are C# specific, and the interfaces language independent.

---

I've uploaded a working version on github: https://github.com/CodesInChaos/Roslyn

It doesn't work for `var` in a `foreach`, but I suspect that's a limitation of the current Roslyn build.

Comment: Re: your last statement: Correct; we did not get `var` fully implemented in `foreach` before the CTP build was finalized, sorry.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can get the shortest legal string to represent a symbol at a given location using the `ToMinimalDisplayString()` extension method that applies to `ISymbol` (note: It's found in `Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp.SymbolDisplay.

Disclaimer: I work at Microsoft on the Roslyn team.

Comment: BTW, you don't need a disclaimer when answering questions _about_ your product.  Disclaimers should be used if you're recommending your product.

Comment: So how would he prefix that line, Harmless Promotion (of answer, not product)?

Comment: @sq33G: Unless he's trying to demonstrate that he knows what he's talking bout, he doesn't need that line at all.  If he is, he could put it in parentheses.

Comment: small addition: to get `TypeSyntax` you can use `SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName(minimalDisplayString)`

Answer (score -1):

Problem: Find the argument type of nullable. It can be custom object or system identifier.

In c# - customobject are having kind() == identifier and bool/string/ are having type Predefined.

This is how you get the type of argument to nullable

[Here identifier name is telling that's is custom object. It can be PredefinedType]

```
 Class A
 {
     public bool ? test;
    public b ? obj1;
 }
 // Get the semantic model and get the property declarationsyntax

 PropertyDeclarationSyntax prop = (get it somehow)[]

 INamedTypeSymbol tp = (INamedTypeSymbol)x.Type;

 string nameoftype = tp.TypeArguments.FirstOrDefault().Name;

 ITypeSymbol s1 = tp.TypeArguments.FirstOrDefault();

 TypeSyntax t1 = SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName(s1.ToMinimalDisplayString(semanticModel, 
 prop.SpanStart));

 t1.kind == IdentifierName meaning its custom object type.
```

Comment: IPropertySymbol x = (IPropertySymbol)semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(prop); -- sorry i missed above