# Getting TypeSyntax from TypeSymbol. Do I really need to re-parse the name?

Tags: roslyn

I want to get `TypeSyntax` from `TypeSymbol`.
Based on the answer to the [Get TypeSyntax from ITypeSymbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231211/get-typesyntax-from-itypesymbol) question, my solution is `Syntax.ParseTypeName(typeSymbol.ToDisplayString())` which doesn't look good.

Is there a more direct solution?

Comment: Do you really want a TypeSyntax, or something like a ClassDeclarationSyntax, which you can get from ISymbol.DeclaringSyntaxReferences?

Comment: I really wanted a `TypeSyntax` instance. My bigger goal is to get a simplest `ExpressionSyntax` that represents a typed expression from an instance of `TypeSymbol`. For that I was trying to create a `ParameterSyntax` instance, but later found out that it wasn't a `ExpressionSyntax` descendant =(

Comment: Can you describe the larger scenario of what you are trying to do?  Maybe there is a different way to approach it.  BTW ParameterSyntax is for formal parameters in declarations, which are definitely not expressions.

Comment: That still doesn't explain what you are trying to accomplish.  WHY do you want to do that.

Comment: OK, I'll tell you why I need that `TypeSyntax` and `ExpressionSyntax` (but I think, I'm going to regret telling it): I'm calling `Binder.BindUnaryOperator` on that syntax to get a proper operator.

Comment: @KevinPilch-Bisson We're having the same requirement: given an ITypeSymbol, get a CSharp `TypeSyntax` that represents the same type. Purpose: We need to generate code based on a type symbol read from a metadata reference. For example, consider a refactoring automatically implementing interfaces represented as a symbol chosen from a referenced assembly.

Comment: Ulrichb: for your case, take a look at the SyntaxGenerator class in Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.dll, which has code to do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for but this works forks for me. I get `TypeSyntax` of declared method parameter using SyntaxReferences this way:

```
(Symbol.DeclaringSyntaxReferences.First().GetSyntax() as ParameterSyntax).Type
```